# Abstract class Dependency Injection in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, abstract-class, autowired

I have a abstract class for login functionality

```
@Component
public abstract class SignIn {    

    public abstract LogInOperationToken signin(User user, HttpServletRequest request);


}
```

which is implemented by two concrete classes `FacebookSignInImpl` and `NormalSignInImpl` which are both annoted as `@Component` as well.

Now, I have a service class as follows:

```
 @Service
public class SignInService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
     private SignIn signIn;    


    public SignInService(@Qualifier("signIn") SignIn signin) {
    this.signIn = signin;
    }


    public LogInOperationToken signin(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return signIn.signin(user,request);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it takes the abstract class as constructor parameter.

From the controller class what I am trying to achieve is to check for some flag and based on that, assign the abstract class the right implementation: normal or facebook signin. Without Spring dependency injection I would do something like:

```
SignIn signIn = null; 

if(flag.equals("facebook")){
    signIn  = new FacebookSignInImpl();
}
else{
    signIn = new NormalSignInImpl();
}

SignInService signInService = new SignInService(signIn);
signInService.signIn(user, request);
```

Since `SignIn` is abstract class how can I `@Autowire` it so that it is assigned to the constructor in `SignInService`. Please comment if you need any more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: See [Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-java).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create `@Component` of abstract class and your application design not perfect. Please follow the below pattern

```
public abstract class SignIn {
    public abstract LogInOperationToken signin(User user, HttpServletRequest request);
}

@Component("fcaebookSignIn")
public class FcaebookSignIn {
    public LogInOperationToken signin(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // implementation code
    }
}

@Component("normalSignIn")
public class NormalSignIn {
    public LogInOperationToken signin(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // implementation code
    }
}
```

And then I strongly recommend you to create different controllers or rest endpoints for different type of signIn

```
@Controller
public class SignInController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="fcaebookSignIn")
    private SignIn fcaebookSignIn;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="normalSignIn")
    private SignIn normalSignIn;

    @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST, path = '/normal/signIn') 
    public User normalSignIn(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        normalSignIn.signIn(user, request);
    }

    @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST, path = '/facebook/signIn') 
    public User facebookSignIn(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        fcaebookSignIn.signIn(user, request);
    }
}
```

But if you have to use a single endpoint then the following should work

```
@Controller
public class SignInController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private SignIn signIn;

    @RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST, path = '/signIn') 
    public User normalSignIn(@RequestBody User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String flag = request.getParameter("flag"); // populate this from wherever you are getting this flag

        if(flag.equals("facebook")) {
            signIn  = context.getBean(FcaebookSignIn.class)
        }
        else{
            signIn  = context.getBean(NormalSignIn.class)
        }

        signIn.signIn(user, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem appears to be in constructor of the  `SignInService` class where I am trying to pass the abstract class as parameter...How do you propose mapping that?

Comment: Do the same thing in service class as I've done in controller class, dont pass the parameter in constructor.